# Cómo pasar una variable de un método a otro

Tags: java

¿Cómo puedo pasar la variable de un método a otro? En este caso quiero pasar la variable"capitalInicial" al método "interesesYNuevoCapital".

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
double capitalInicial=pedirCantidadCalcularIntereses();
interesesYNuevoCapital();
}
public static double pedirCantidadCalcularIntereses(){
double capitalInicial=500;
return capitalInicial;
}
public static double pedirCantidadCalcularIntereses(){
System.out.println(capitalInicial);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeramente, el método `interesesYNuevoCapital` debe recibir esa variable como parámetro.

Por ejemplo:

```
public static void interesesYNuevoCapital(double capitalInicial){
    System.out.println(capitalInicial);
}
```

Luego, ya puedes pasarla al método:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double capitalInicial=pedirCantidadCalcularIntereses();
    interesesYNuevoCapital(capitalInicial);
}
```

En el ejemplo `interesesYNuevoCapital` fue declarado con `void`, asumiendo que dicho método no retorna nada.

Para más detalles puedes ver la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html), más específicamente el apartado **Passing Primitive Data Type Arguments**.

Answer (score 2):

Debes modificar el método `interesesYNuevoCapital()` para que este reciba un tipo de valor como el indicado en `capitalInicial`  que sería un valor de tipo`double`:

```
public static void interesesYNuevoCapital(double capitalInicial){
    ...
    ...
}
```

de esta forma puedes enviar el valor indicado:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
double capitalInicial=pedirCantidadCalcularIntereses();
interesesYNuevoCapital(capitalInicial);
}
```

Revisa la documentación oficial:

**[Pasar información a un método o un constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)** (inglés)